# ASP.NET web-application example for newbies

Tags: web-development, asp.net, web-applications

I want to learn ASP.NET web-application development by example. I want to learn it from an already developed web-application that is good as a tutorial for newbies. A fully functional web application that is small but powerful enough to teach newbies the development effort required for web-application development. I am looking for some application that is made using software engineering principles and not just a code written haphazardly.

Comment: Check out http://www.nerddinner.com/ if you want to look at some code, link to the source code at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 different flavors of ASP.NET.

WebForms

and MVC See here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47537/asp-net-webforms-or-asp-net-mvc for the difference.

For MVC 
Go here http://www.asp.net/mvc and look at all the tutorials in particular the [Music Store App demo](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1)

To learn WebForms go here http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Comment: I highly recommend you don't learn WebForms as less you need to. MVC is simply better to work with coming from a new and fresh perspective.

Comment: @Rayons @Daveo Why is there an emphasis not to learn WebForms!

Comment: Music Store App Demo looks nice to start with! :)

Comment: @A-Cube see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726755/should-i-learn-mvc-or-web-forms and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661181/asp-net-mvc-vs-webforms  basically webforms is the older way to do things and is still ok to use for some Interal websites and you may have to update an existing systems that uses webforms. However for external websites and most new sites they will be written in MVC .NET as it works more inline with how the Internet was intended to work (stateless).